# Finding the voltage and current at t = 0 using Step Response

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, short-circuit, homework, step-response

The question that I'm trying to solve is as follows:

> In the circuit shown below, the switch has been closed for a long time. a) What is v(0) or the voltage across the capacitor immediately after the switch is opened? b) What is i(0) and i1(0)?

[image]

First, I calculated for the voltage before t = 0 using voltage division. I arrived at *v(0-) = 4V*. Since the capacitor voltage cannot change instantaneously, I assumed that 4V is the voltage at t=0.

Here's the tricky part. I'm asked to find the current at t = 0. By looking at the diagram, I am certain that the 1-ohm resistor is short-circuited, so I simply dismissed that and used Ohm's Law to find *i1(0-)* using v = 20 V and R = 4 ohms. In the property of short circuit, the *i* is equal to 0.

Are my solutions for *i1* and *i* legal to begin with? I'm only confident with 4V as the voltage at t = 0.

Comment: Is the question asking for currents at \$0^-\$ or \$0^+\$ (i.e. before or after switch opening) ?  Also, what do you mean by 1 ohm resistor is short circuited ? after \$t=0\$, it is effectively removed from the circuit by the open switch.

Comment: You need to take into account the voltage across the capacitor at t=0+ (you already found this) when calculating the instantaneous current flow in the 4 ohm resistor.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg, the diagram has two currents in question--i1 and i. Are they assumed to be equal?

Comment: @romeoPH  Immediately after the switch is opened, what can you say about i1 and 1? (This is not an assumption; use KCL)

Answer (score 1):

Homework guidance:

Nobody shorts the 1 Ohm resistor, its end is opened so its current is stopped at t=0. Before t=0 there were 4A as your voltage division shows.

At t=0 the circuit changes. You have 4V in the capacitor, 20V in the source and a resistor between. The capacitor charges towards 20V starting from 4V. Find the formulas.

Comment: "Before t=0 there were 4A as your voltage division shows."

Do you mean 4 V?

Comment: 4V means also 4A in the 1Ohm resistor when the resistor is still connected.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that i1 is equal to i in this case since the 4-ohm resistor and the capacitor are in series (and therefore, have the same current)?

Comment: After the switch is opened i1=1, there's no other way left for the current. Being in series means the current is the same literally.

Comment: What do you mean by i1=1? That the current is the same?

Comment: Well, I applied KVL. My equation for the loop around the 20V, 4V, and 4-ohms is -20 + 4i + 4 = 0. Is this a correct step?

Comment: OOPS I mean i1=i. Sorry for not reading what I wrote.

Comment: i1=(20V-v)/4Ohm and that's the fact.

Comment: ..which makes i1 = i = 4 A! This proves that my KVL setup three comments back is correct. Thanks for your time!